# I do not get response from database like Error is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

Tags: mongodb, express

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

let db;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ecom', (err, client) => {
  if (err) throw err

 db = client.db('ecom');

})


app.get("/", (req, res) => {

    db.collection('products').find().toArray((err, result) => {

      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      res.send(result);
      
    });
    
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening on port 3000"))
```

I want to try get data from database. But i know other method also present as well but what is the problem in above code.

Comment: What is the error? Please include all helpful details, otherwise we have to guess what the problem is. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

> MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Introduction:
Are you grappling with a baffling MongoDB connection problem after upgrading to Node.js version 18? Don't fret – there's a quick solution that can save you time and frustration. Resolving MongoDB Connection Issues After Node.js Version 18.

The Problem:
After upgrading to Node.js v18, some developers encounter a vexing issue while connecting to their local MongoDB server. Despite seemingly accurate configurations, they face the dreaded ECONNREFUSED error.

The Solution:
The key lies in the way you structure your MongoDB connection string. Previously, using localhost was common practice:
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/your_database');

However, with Node.js v18, opting for the explicit IP address 127.0.0.1 in the connection string does the trick:
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/your_database');

Conclusion:
When MongoDB connections hiccup post-Node.js v18 upgrade, the remedy is simpler than anticipated. By choosing 127.0.0.1 over localhost in your connection string, you can effortlessly resolve the ECONNREFUSED error and restore seamless MongoDB connectivity.